# New to PCB design: Does routing a wire on a 2nd layer underneath a pad connection effect cause a connection issue?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, wiring, pad, router

I am designing a pcb with minimal room approximately 5.5mm wide, the power supply comes from one end of the board. The top layer has pad connections that take up most of the width of the board leaving little to no room to route. Will it cause an issue to route wires on the bottom layer directly underneath the pads? I am concerned this will create connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

Usually no, it will add a few 10's of femto-farads of capacitance (at most) and some high resistance (100MΩ+ usually but depends on layer height) from FR4 if you can draw in femto-farad capacitors or max 0.1pf between the routed signals and the pads, and you don't think it will affect your design then you'll be ok.

If you are really worried about it, you can find the capacitance between two nets with a PCB calculator (like saturn PCB tool)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by pad - however, any hole through the board will create a connection between the sides for any track or other copper that hits that hole.

If you have a pad or copper area on one side of the board that does not have a hole through the board, it will not connect to anything on the other side of the board.